# Calculating Aspect Ratio for all sizes of iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

I know this types question has been asked several times but i am newer to iphone so confused with all answers.As my logo is 61*57 and i want to change according to size of iphone. but when i specify it's aspect ratio for all screen it gives their own ratio. But I am confused how this ratio has been calculated. for 5.5 inch they have recommende 17:184 for 4.7 61:667 4 inch 61:568 and for 3.5 inches 61:480.

Comment: You want to change the size of icon according to the screen sizE?

Comment: Yes i want to change according to screen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So first You give X , Y and aspect ration to the icon
[image]

Then you give your icon's heigh equal to superview's height

[image]

Then you divide your current icon's height by superview's height that you just gave

[image]

the you write that divided answer in `Equal height to: Superview`'s `Multiplier:`

[image]

And its done

[image]

Comment: Thanks its helped me a lot.