# multiplier to the width and height in objective-c

Tags: ios

How to give multiplier to the width and height of the UIImageView .

I need to add the constraint to the image with have a height of 200*400-1x,400*1600-2x   .I have  set the  constraints in the 12.9 iPad .

Comment: Please check this link . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455194/calculating-aspect-ratio-for-all-sizes-of-iphone/35455631#35455631

Comment: pls go through : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html

Comment: Where does `x` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Do it programmatically.
Create an IBoutlet for your constraints.
Update your constraint accordingly.
yourConstraint.constant =  200*400-1x

Answer (score 0):

This constraint give the image view 0.7 of the width of the view

```
 [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.imageView
      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth 
      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
      toItem:self.view 
      attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth 
      multiplier:0.7
      constant:0]];
```